# How do you get this function in terms of x and y?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to model an equation for a graph of distance from origin, per second. There was a question on the physics forum that I am trying to model in mathematical terms, but I'm stuck...

Anyway, the table of values I got was:

x = 0, y = 0
x = 1, y = 4
x = 2, y = 12
x = 3, y = 24
x = 4, y = 40

Where $x$ is time in seconds, and $y$ is distance from starting point of 0 in meters.

This table was "inuited" based on the distance from the starting point of a car moving with a constant acceleration of $4\frac{m}{s^2}$.

The algorithm in my head that I was using was:

$f(x) = f(x-1) + 4x$

Basically, you use the previous $y$ value (the last distance you were from the origin) and add the velocity that the car is moving at the current time in order to get the current distance from the origin.

If it matters at all, the first derivative (velocity) and second derivative (acceleration) are $4x$ and $4$ respectively.

**How do I get this in terms of x and y?**

## EDIT

Basically, I'm trying to get an equation for the table above that shows y as a function of x.

The equation I currently have looks like it relies on you knowing the previous y value ($f(x-1)$).

## EDIT 2

AS pointed out in several comments, the first derivative should be $4x + 2$.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I think he is looking for a function $y(x)$ that fits on the given data points. But I'm not sure

Comment: The table shows, presumably, the distance from origin with initial speed 2 and acceleration 4. The formula is $y(t) = 2t+2 t^2$.

Comment: But there's something wrong with the given. The velocity can't be $4x$. Integrating this and replacing it in the equation given for $f$ creates a contradiction.

Comment: I have no idea what the $f$ is suppose to be. I don't know what the OP is trying to do. Solve an acceleration problem? Fit a curve to some data? Extract some parameters from data? I have really no idea. Hence my first comment.

Comment: @copper.hat, see my edit in my post. Also, the f is just function notation, f isn't a variable.

Comment: I believe copper.hat is correct. The equation can only be $f(x)=2x^2 +2x$.

Comment: But then you'll have to adjust your velocity to $4x + 2$.

Comment: @JoshBeam: Look at my second comment. This is a standard constant acceleration formula with specified initial speed and position.

Comment: @copper.hat, thanks, I didn't know about the constant acceleration formula.

Comment: @JoshBeam: See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/acons.html for example.

Answer (score 2):

This is a difference equation. They can be hard to solve, but not in this case.
We'll use $f_{x}=f_{x-1}+4x$ instead of $f(x)=f(x-1)+4x$. $f_0$ equals 0 so subsitute to find $f_1$. You should get $f_1=0+4=4$. Take this value, increase x to 2, and substitute again. You'll get 12. Written as an expansion 
$$x_1=4$$
$$x_2=(4)+4*2$$
$$x_3=((4)+4*2)+4*3)$$
$$f_n=4+4*2+4*3+4*4...+4*n$$
Factor out the 4 and realize this is just a sum of natural numbers, which equals ${n^2+n}\over 2$, I'll omit the proof.
Factor in the 4 and substitue x=n and you'll get $$f(x)=2(x^2+x)$$
In terms of y
$$y=2(x^2+x)$$
You're correct about the derivatives.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. So this depends on you knowing an initial value then, correct? Also, I believe I did get the first derivative wrong, as it should be 4x + 2, right?

Comment: Correct, its very similar to the arbitrary constant that appears when evaluating indefinite integrals. Yes, I miss read that, 4x+2 for the first derivative, and 4 for the second derivative.